# I am making a phone number validator in regex I want to check whether it is 10 character long or not?

Tags: regex

```js
 function telephoneChecker(str){
 return /\d{10}/.test(str)
 }
 telephoneChecker('5555555555')
```

I want it to return false if it is more than 10 character long? how can i do this?
please help

Answer (score 1):

Your regex test whether there are 10-digits anywhere in the string. It could be at the start, middle or the end of the string. i.e. it doesn't say the string has to be exactly a 10-digit number it only has to contain a 10-digit number within. This is why you would be getting a false positive for strings containing more than 10 digits. To make it exact, your regex needs ^ and $ to anchor the regex to the start and end of the string, i.e.

```js
function telephoneChecker(str){
  return /^\d{10}$/.test(str);
}

console.log(telephoneChecker('5555555555')); // true
console.log(telephoneChecker('55555555558')); // false
```